# Javascript doesn't work when have another one

Tags: javascript, wordpress, post, random, block

I searched but I didn't find the answer.

I have a code that change the color of my wordpress template blocks and posts randomly. Actually it changes the classes of these blocks and so the colors. You can see the code here:

```
function inArray(array , exist) {
    var rslt = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] == exist)
        {
            rslt = true;
        }
    }
    return rslt;
}

var colored = Array();
function changeColor(target) {
    var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName(target);
    var blockLength = blocks.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < blockLength; i++)
    {
        if (colored.length >= 9)
        {
            colored = [];
        }
        var rand = 0;
        while (rand == 0 || inArray(colored , rand))
        {
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)%10;
        }
        colored.push(rand);
        blocks[i].className = target+' color'+rand ;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    changeColor('block');
    changeColor('post');
}
```

the code you seen placed in an external file named 'colors.js' and included by:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/colors.js"></script>
```

in my wordpress template.
the code works correctly til I add another code like this:

```
<script>var _mxvtmw_position = 'left', _mxvtmw_domain = 'icomp.ir'</script>
<script src="http://iwfcdn.iranwebfestival.com/js/mx.vtmw.min.js?12688" async="async"></script>
```

Why? And how can i fix this problem?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**: 
DEMO: http://tuts.icomp.ir/

Comment: You are trying to apply a style to a non-existent selector on line 56 in colors.js. #mihanblog (var prev="mihanblog";) does not exist.

Comment: thank you but i removed this code and it doesn't work again. :|

Answer (score -2):

IN CASE blocks.length IS 1 YOU HAVE TO ADD ONE MORE IF CONDITION

```
if (blocks.length==undefined){
//code
}
```

Comment: excuse me , i didn't understand. can you give me an example? or explain it? thank you.

Comment: First of all JavaScript is case sensitive, so `IF` will throw a syntax error. Secondly, you are **assigning** `undefined` to `blocks.length`, instead of comparing it. And how does the code example relate to the sentence you have written?

Comment: So what's the point of the comparison now? `blocks.length` will **never** be `undefined`, so this block never executed.

Comment: @ Felix Kling In javasript i have faced this problem when blocks.length==1 it doesn't work , but blocks.length==undefined works in that case .

Comment: @RajuRathore But it will never be undefined because we always have at least a block. and usually over than 5! And after that , where i wrote `blocks.length == 1` to change it to `blocks.length == undefined`? I just wrote a for loop!